# Java Bit-wise Nor

Tags: java

I have to do `Boolean` operation like,

```
 B1=00 10 11 01 00 
 B2=00 10 11 01  
 B1 NOR B2 =11 11 11 11
```

How is it possible in Java ? Can anybody help ?

Sorry, I forgot to mention, is it possible in Java to perform this bit wise NOR operation from the left always without  shifting (B2 has less bits) ?

Comment: Do a bit wise or `|` and then a bitwise not `~`.

Comment: how do you get B1 and B2? `byte` ? `bit[]` ? `integer[]` ? `char[]` ?

Comment: Are you sure you're not asking for XNOR? b1 xnor b2 is 11 11 11 11 based on your example...

Comment: @Tung, Sorry, I ask for XNOR. However, main issue is not with the gate, with the unequal bit length. Thanks for correction.

Comment: @Marek Sebera, I am using INT.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `b1` and `b2` are your (int) variables, the expression would be:

```
~(b1 | b2)
```

For more info, see [Bitwise and Bit Shift Operators](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html).

However, in your example the variables have different lengths. The result doesn't correspond to a NOR either.

**Update:** if you have two sequences of boolean values, no equal size, and only need a portion of it (left to right), I'd suggest using a [`BitSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html):

```
BitSet b1 = new BitSet();
// Fill it with booleans:
for ( int i = 0 ; i < myBooleans.length ; i++ )
    b1.set(i, myBooleans[i]);
// Or fill it with bytes:
BitSet b1 = BitSet.valueOf(myBytes);
// Or fill it with 0/1 from a string:
for ( int i = 0 ; i < myString.length() ; i++ )
    b1.set(i, myString.charAt(i) == "1");

BitSet b2 = new BitSet();
// Same as above

BitSet result = new BitSet();
result.or(b1); // Copies b1
result.or(b2); // Makes the OR
result.flip(0,result.size()); // Negates - the result is a NOR
result.clear(Math.min(b1.size(), b2.size()), result.size()); // Only retain the common size
```

If you really want to use `int`, then it's better to represent it right to left (i.e. the first bit is `b % 2`, the second is `b / 2 % 2`, etc. Then you just have to do the NOR as explained in the beginning, and if necessary truncate the result.

If they are represented left to right, I believe a shift will be necessary (or a multiplication/division, which is essentially the same thing, but more expensive...), unless they are padded with 0's (ex.: `B1=0010 1101 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000`, `B2=0010 1101 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000`). In this case you can do the operation normally.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention, is it possible in Java to perform this bit wise NOR operation from the left always without shifting or adding bits (B2 has less bits) ?

Comment: How are B1 and B2 represented? (int, boolean[], String...) Or maybe you haven't chosen a representation yet, and need a suggestion too?

Comment: Sorry for the delay, answer updated. If you need more info, please explain better how the values are represented (where the input booleans came from, how you stored them in the int, etc).

Answer (score 3):

Nor is just "not or", so just do bitwise or and invert.

`B1 nor B2 = ~(B1|B2);`

Your example doesn't make sense to me though. Why is `(2'b11 NOR 2'b11) = 2'b11?`

Answer (score 3):

xor b1 with B2, then "not" the result:

```
B1 xnor B2 = ~(B1^B2)
```

Comment: Thanks, but it gives wrong result with unequal bits. Because, It is doing XNOR operation from the left.