# Exclusive NOR in Java

Tags: java

Do we have any exclusive NOR operator in java. I see that Java has caret( ^) as exclusive OR. But I am not able get the exclusive NOR operation using the expression ~ (x ^y)

Edit:
I tried `~(x^y)`. But it givrs me a different rrsult.

For ex:

```
int x = 0b1001, y = 0b0011;

System.out.println ( ~(x^y));
```

Gives me `-11`. But I am supposed to get 5. I believe i am getting -11 since int has 4 bytes, and the extra bits are not handled properly.

Comment: Do you mean a logical xnor or a bitwise xnor?

Comment: Bit wise NOR. Related to bitwise operators.

Comment: Did you check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9659622/java-bit-wise-nor ?

Comment: Please post your test case as to why you think the above isn't working as a bit-wise XNOR as it should as written.

Comment: Edited my post with test case. I used Paul's suggestion and it works

Answer (score 2):

`~(x^y)` is a bitwise XNOR that works for `int` values or `long` values.

`!(x^y)` is a logical XNOR that works for `boolean`s.

Java only does bitwise operations on `32` or `64` bit numbers, so you cannot expect the correct result for a `4`-bit calculation.

To get the answer you want you have to do `~(x^y) & 0xF`. `0xF` only has the last 4 bits set, so gives the desired result.